# How do I move a GameObject at the same speed as onMouseDrag?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying click on a GameObject and move it at the same rate as the mouse.  I am able to get the Object to move, but I have to do some crazy modifications in order for it to not vanish off the screen.

Note: My ultimate goal will be to do this for mobile, but am starting with the mouse.

```
public class ItemController : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 startPos;
    private bool ObjectMouseDown = false;

    void Update()
    {
       Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition + new Vector3(0,0,15));
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        startPos = transform.position;
        ObjectMouseDown = true;
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if (ObjectMouseDown == true)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Input.mousePosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 5), Time.deltaTime * 2f);
          //      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, endPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        ObjectMouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

Notice how I have to add a z-value of 15, so that the object doesn't float up out of the screen.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input.mousePosition` return the absolute pixel position on the screen and not world position. You need to use `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` something like this

```
Vector3 mouseWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.position.x, Input.position.y, 15);
transform.position = mouseWorldPos;
```

You can read more here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html